# Blank Google Maps MapView in android

Tags: android, google-maps

My problem at the moment is that the MapView in my application is always blank regardless of what I have done so far. I got the SH:IA key and package name, generated my code, and placed it in both the "google_maps_key.xml" files in the "debug/res/values" folder and the "release/res/values" folder, and this is the result:

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgH4U.png)

Manifest:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.flashitdelivery.flash_it_partner">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

<application android:allowBackup="true" android:name=".activity.MyApplication" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".activity.SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>
    <!--Auth0 Lock-->
    <activity android:name="com.auth0.lock.LockActivity" android:theme="@style/Lock.Theme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="a0iYoER9BjZdrjeOhRmwov6o3ppirgsETj"
                android:host="flashit.auth0.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.auth0.lock.client-id" android:value="@string/auth0_client_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.auth0.lock.domain-url" android:value="@string/auth0_domain" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <!--Auth0 Lock End-->
</application>
```

Dependencies:

```css
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.auth0.android:lock:1.14.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Layout:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@color/flashItPartner_purple"
        android:id="@+id/driverUpperIcons">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/driverUpperIcons"
        android:apiKey="@string/google_maps_key"
        android:id="@+id/googleMapObject"></com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/googleMapObject"></LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

I have no idea as to how I can fix this issue. I was hoping that someone could guide me in the correct direction.

Comment: I was able to solve it. I forgot to implement onResume

Answer (score 0):

I normally use this version of the map fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Also, always make sure you have internet permission, add google play services to the build.gradle file and then it should work now!

Comment: I already have the permissions and I added google play services (as you can see in the dependency code).

Comment: Okay, so have you switched to SupportMapFragment ? Mine totally works and mind you, for backwards compatibility;

Answer (score 0):

Check for the official documentation. It's very good explained!

Link: [Maps Android API for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add your Api key to `Manifest` like that in your `Application` tag:

```
<application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="yourapikey" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Then use `Fragment` like :

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the same `SHA1` finger print in API console that your project built with, generate the [SHA-1 key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#add_the_api_key_to_your_application), use it to get the API key and place it in the meta data present in manifest file.

Check your developer console if you [enabled](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#get_an_api_key_from_the_console_name) the `Google Maps Android API` also check your logcat, there might be some error log about Google Map.

You may check this demo app demostrate how to use Google Maps API: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples

For more details how to solve the issue, check the Official Documentation here, follow the steps how to create app project including map activity: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start